# Dundas Join two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, dashboard, dundas

I am new to Databases. I came across a peculiar problem with two tables. Please let me know the solution.

I am working on Dundas Dashboard version 4, Database is SQL Server 2008R2

Please find the scenario below

an `incidentdimvw` table having two columns `classification` and `id`

a `displaystringdimvw` table having column name `elementname`
and from `displaystringdimvw` table having another column name `displayname` as classification, which is my need.

> incidentdimvw    ||    displaystringdimvw
>
> (id)   (classification)            || (displayname)"classification"     (elementname)
>
> (ir23)    (enum.email)       ||    (email)    (enum.email)
>
> (ir56)   (enum.Printing)   ||  (Printing)  ((enum.Printing)

The end result should be like this.

> (id)   (Classification)
>
> (ir23)   (Email)
>
> (ir56)   (Printing)

Is this solution possible from these two tables in Dundas dashboard. Please help me in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

you can define a relationship between the two tables at the virtual table level using the "Add Relationship" function. you can use one of the standard SQL joins. keep in mind that they have to be on the same data connector. here's a link that will help you with the details on how to define them: http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard4.VirtualStructures_DefiningRelationships.ashx